# SQL inner join, order by timestamp in two tables

Tags: sql, inner-join

How do I order inner join output from the timestamp in two different tables?

```
| id |      event |                  timestamp |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     passed |        2019-06-05 11:55:44 |
|  1 |     failed |        2019-06-09 08:19:35 |


| id |      event |                  timestamp |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 | email_sent |        2019-06-05 11:56:44 |
|  1 | email_sent |        2019-06-09 08:20:35 |
```

Desired Result:

```
| id |      event |                  timestamp |
------------------------------------------------
|  1 |     passed |        2019-06-05 11:55:44 |
|  1 | email_sent |        2019-06-05 11:56:44 |
|  1 |     failed |        2019-06-09 08:19:35 |
|  1 | email_sent |        2019-06-09 08:20:35 |
```

This is what I have so far, however it orders TableA by the timestamp and then TableB by the timestamp, instead of ordering by all timestamps at once:

```
SELECT TableA.*, TableB.* FROM TableA 
        INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.id=TableB.id
        WHERE TableA.id='1' ORDER BY TableA.timestamp, TableB.timestamp
```

Comment: Your desired result doesn't look like you want to join the two tables. You might want to union the tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want `union all`:

```
select id, event, timestamp 
from tablea
union all
select id, event, timestamp 
from tableb
order by timestamp;
```

You can add `where id = 1` to each subquery, if you want to filter the rows.

Comment: I think you should also order by Id, for example for one ID 3 event has done but at same time if another id's event done it will be show in middle of those rows.